# Error - The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-insert

When using EF Code First migrations, I get an error when CREATING an Item with code in the database.

I've reviewed several QAs on stackoverflow similar to my question, but they do not help me solve my problem. I am not using automatic migrations.

I followed this tutorial, http://mahedee.net/cascading-dropdown-list-in-asp-net-mvc-a-sample-demonstration/#comment-17847 for creating cascading dropdownlists for MainCategories/SubCategories and it works fine in my list, but when I go to create an Item, I get the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Fabrics_dbo.MainCategories_MainCategoryId". The conflict occurred in database "MyFabricStashAppDb", table "dbo.MainCategories", column 'MainCategoryId'. The statement has been terminated.

My models are as follows:
My MainCategory.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyFabricStashApp.Models
{
    public class MainCategory
    {
        public int MainCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<SubCategory1> SubCategories1 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My SubCategory1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyFabricStashApp.Models
{
    public class SubCategory1
    {
        public int SubCategory1Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int MainCategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual MainCategory MainCategory { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My Fabric.cs (Item class)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyFabricStashApp.Models
{
    public class Fabric
    {
        public int FabricId { get; set; } //Item Number

        public int MainCategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual MainCategory MainCategory { get; set; }

        public int SubCategory1Id { get; set; }
        public virtual SubCategory1 SubCategory1 { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; } //Knit, Woven, Voile, Interfacing, Denim, Suiting, etc.
        public string Weight { get; set; }//Lightweight, Medium, Heavy
        public string Content { get; set; }//Cotton, Polyester, Nylon, etc.
        public string Design { get; set; }//Marvel Comics, Amy Butler, etc.
        public string Brand { get; set; } //Springs Creative Products, Free Spirit, Robert Kaufman, etc.
        public double Quantity { get; set; }//.25 yd, .50 yd, .75 yd, 1.0 yd, etc.
        public int Width { get; set; }// in inches, ie. 44", 54", etc.
        public string Source { get; set; }//Joann
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
        public int ItemsSold { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my Migration class "Add-migration FirstMigration"

```
namespace MyFabricStashApp.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class FirstMigration : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Fabrics",
                c => new
                    {
                        FabricId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        MainCategoryId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        SubCategory1Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Name = c.String(),
                        ImagePath = c.String(),
                        Location = c.String(),
                        Type = c.String(),
                        Weight = c.String(),
                        Content = c.String(),
                        Design = c.String(),
                        Brand = c.String(),
                        Quantity = c.Double(nullable: false),
                        Width = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Source = c.String(),
                        Notes = c.String(),
                        ItemsSold = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.FabricId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.MainCategories", t => t.MainCategoryId, cascadeDelete: false)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.SubCategory1", t => t.SubCategory1Id, cascadeDelete: false)
                .Index(t => t.MainCategoryId)
                .Index(t => t.SubCategory1Id);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.MainCategories",
                c => new
                    {
                        MainCategoryId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.MainCategoryId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.SubCategory1",
                c => new
                    {
                        SubCategory1Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(),
                        MainCategoryId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.SubCategory1Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.MainCategories", t => t.MainCategoryId, cascadeDelete: false)
                .Index(t => t.MainCategoryId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Purchases",
                c => new
                    {
                        PurchaseId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        PurchaseDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        PurchaseQuantity = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        PurchasePrice = c.Double(nullable: false),
                        FabricId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.PurchaseId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Fabrics", t => t.FabricId, cascadeDelete: false)
                .Index(t => t.FabricId);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Fabrics", "SubCategory1Id", "dbo.SubCategory1");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Purchases", "FabricId", "dbo.Fabrics");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Fabrics", "MainCategoryId", "dbo.MainCategories");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.SubCategory1", "MainCategoryId", "dbo.MainCategories");
            DropIndex("dbo.Purchases", new[] { "FabricId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.SubCategory1", new[] { "MainCategoryId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Fabrics", new[] { "SubCategory1Id" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Fabrics", new[] { "MainCategoryId" });
            DropTable("dbo.Purchases");
            DropTable("dbo.SubCategory1");
            DropTable("dbo.MainCategories");
            DropTable("dbo.Fabrics");
        }
    }
}
```

My FabricListViewModel.cs - I created this to give the View access to all the properties I need from all my classes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyFabricStashApp.Models
{
    public class FabricListViewModel
    {
        public int FabricId { get; set; } //Item Number

        public int MainCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string MainCategoryName { get; set; }

        public int SubCategory1Id { get; set; }
        public string SubCategory1Name { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; } //Knit, Woven, Voile, Interfacing, Denim, Suiting, etc.
        public string Weight { get; set; }//Lightweight, Medium, Heavy
        public string Content { get; set; }//Cotton, Polyester, Nylon, etc.
        public string Design { get; set; }//Marvel Comics, Amy Butler, etc.
        public string Brand { get; set; } //Springs Creative Products, Free Spirit, Robert Kaufman, etc.
        public double Quantity { get; set; }//.25 yd, .50 yd, .75 yd, 1.0 yd, etc.
        public int Width { get; set; }// in inches, ie. 44", 54", etc.
        public string Source { get; set; }//Joann
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public int ItemsSold { get; set; }
        public int PurchaseCount { get; set; }

    }
}
```

In my controller, FabricController, you can see I am Including MainCategory and SubCategory1 models in my List, so I can access their properties. I've included the Index action and POST Create Action for brevity.

```
public class FabricController : Controller
    {
        private MyFabricStashDb db = new MyFabricStashDb();

        // GET: Fabric
        public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = null)
        {
            var model = db.Fabrics.Include(f => f.MainCategory).Include(f => f.SubCategory1)
                .OrderByDescending(f => f.ItemsSold)
                .Where(f => searchTerm == null || f.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm))
                .Select(f => new FabricListViewModel
                {
                    FabricId = f.FabricId,
                    Name = f.Name,
                    MainCategoryId = f.MainCategoryId,
                    MainCategoryName = f.MainCategory.Name,
                    SubCategory1Id = f.SubCategory1Id,
                    SubCategory1Name = f.SubCategory1.Name,
                    ImagePath = f.ImagePath,
                    Location = f.Location,
                    Type = f.Type,
                    Weight = f.Weight,
                    Content = f.Content,
                    Design = f.Design,
                    Brand = f.Brand,
                    Quantity = f.Quantity,
                    Width = f.Width,
                    Source = f.Source,
                    Notes = f.Notes,
                    ItemsSold = f.ItemsSold,
                    PurchaseCount = f.Purchases.Count()
                });
            return View(model);
        }
// POST: Fabric/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "FabricId,MainCategory,SubCategory1,SubCategory2,Name,ImagePath,Location,Type,Weight,Content,Design,Brand,Quantity,Width,Source,Notes,ItemsSold")] Fabric fabric, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string fabricId = fabric.FabricId.ToString();
                string myfile = fabricId + "_" + filename;
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images"), myfile);
                fabric.ImagePath = myfile;
                file.SaveAs(path);
                db.Fabrics.Add(fabric);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(fabric);
        }
```

Do I need to BIND the properties from the MainCategory and SubCategory1 classes in my POST Create method? Could that be why the INSERT statement is failing? It is failing on the "db.SaveChanges();" line in the POST Create action method.

When I comment out the lines `public virtual MainCategory MainCategory {get; set;}` property in the Fabric class, it works and I'm able to create a new Item, however I cannot INCLUDE those classes in my FabricController because the properties don't exist in the Fabric class, so then I cannot access their properties.

Comment: Long post; short question: do you know, in general, what can cause this error `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint`?

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you create a `Fabric` entity that has a `MainCategoryId` that does not exist in the `MainCategory` table.

Comment: If so, please set a breakpoint somewhere in `public ActionResult Create`. Check with your debugger if all the required properties of `Fabric fabric` are filled.

Comment: One of the fields probably isn't filled correctly. If you found the bottleneck, you can focus your question more on that detail.

Comment: I've never used this Bind attribute to do model binding for MVC, but one thing that jumped out at me was this:  "[Bind(Include = "FabricId,MainCategory,SubCategory1..."   Your MainCategory and SubCategory appear to be similar to object references, while the rest of those included fields look like field references....meaning, should MainCategory be MainCategoryId instead of just MainCategory.  juharr and Stefan are both correct in that your MainCategoryId field that is trying to be stored in the DB is not properly filled out...could this binding be why they are not being sent over properly?

Comment: @juharr - Thank you! You were right! The POST create method was not binding MainCategoryId and SubCategory1Id. I added them to my BIND statement and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Yep, user1011627, you came in just after I posted my comment, but you are right too, thanks for the help guys!

Comment: No problem...glad you got it working.  You may want to post the resolution as an answer in the event someone stumbles across it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting the resolution to my problem here. It was answered in comments by @juharr and @user1011627 above but I wanted to post the solution in case someone encounters the same problem.

I simply added "MainCategoryId" and "SubCategory1Id" properties to my BIND statement in the POST Create action method. See below, in the FabricController:

```
// POST: Fabric/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "FabricId,MainCategory,MainCategoryId, SubCategory1Id,SubCategory1,SubCategory2,Name,ImagePath,Location,Type,Weight,Content,Design,Brand,Quantity,Width,Source,Notes,ItemsSold")] Fabric fabric, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string fabricId = fabric.FabricId.ToString();
                string myfile = fabricId + "_" + filename;
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images"), myfile);
                fabric.ImagePath = myfile;
                file.SaveAs(path);
                db.Fabrics.Add(fabric);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(fabric);
        }
```

I'm sure there are other ways to do it, but this was the simplest and quickest solution for me to get it working with my other code in the application.

Comment: is it possible, that you don't know much about the binding process? (no offense :) ) 
I would really recommend reading some minutes about it, it helps alot to understand how it works and why it is necessary. Just read, where the link in your generated code points you to => https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598

Comment: no offense taken, but that's why I post questions on here, so I can better understand programming. I completely understand data binding in web forms, but  I know that is ancient history compared to MVC. Thanks all for the help! K.

Answer (score 0):

Loooong question, here's a way to simplify your data.  Every subcategory has a unique id.  To link to a main category you can go via the subcategory that a fabric belongs to.  That gives us

```
public class Fabric
    {
        public int FabricId { get; set; } //Item Number

        // public int MainCategoryId { get; set; }
        // public virtual MainCategory MainCategory { get; set; }

        public int SubCategory1Id { get; set; }
        public virtual SubCategory1 SubCategory1 { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; } //Knit, Woven, Voile, Interfacing, Denim, Suiting, etc.
        public string Weight { get; set; }//Lightweight, Medium, Heavy
        public string Content { get; set; }//Cotton, Polyester, Nylon, etc.
        public string Design { get; set; }//Marvel Comics, Amy Butler, etc.
        public string Brand { get; set; } //Springs Creative Products, Free Spirit, Robert Kaufman, etc.
        public double Quantity { get; set; }//.25 yd, .50 yd, .75 yd, 1.0 yd, etc.
        public int Width { get; set; }// in inches, ie. 44", 54", etc.
        public string Source { get; set; }//Joann
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
        public int ItemsSold { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
    }
```

And so long as you retrieve Fabric by

```
db.Fabrics.Include("SubCategory1").Include("SubCategory1.MainCategory").FirstOrDefault(p => p.FabricId == <something>);
```

You can reference Fabric.SubCategory1.MainCategory.Name

Using MainCategory/SubCategory1 to populate dropdowns and make sure to put SubCategory1 key into your Fabric record on creation.  Should simplify your life.  Your dropdowns would bind to a temp field for MainCategory and your listmodel for SubCategory1.SubCategoryId.  For display, you would populate temp field from Fabric.SubCategory1.MainCategory.MainCategoryId field.  ymmv.